# Python upgrade 2.2 to 2.7 getting long to C long overflowexception

Tags: python, exception, dictionary, overflow

I'm upgrading a old project of mine,
the previous Python version was 2.2 so it is a bit of a jump to 2.7.

The most stuff is working for now ... i had a lot of has_key checks i had to change them to the new  'in' operator.

I'm getting some OverflowError exeptions, like ":Python long convert to C long" and ":Python int too large to convert to C long".

I've searched for the error since 6 hours but i don't get it ...

Everytime i copy the child elements of my dict into my elements dict i get a overlow error like, ":Python int too large to convert to C long".

Could it be that i can't add big objects to a dict?

```
self.elems[name] = child # gives overflowexception
```

child is a object

```
parent.childs[idx] = GridSlotWindow()
```

I simply can't figure out why this is working with python 2.2 but not with python 2.7,
i even get overlow errors when i do "**_*contains*_**" on a large dictionary.

```
def checkkeylst(self, name, value, key_list):

    for DataKey in key_list:
        if DataKey not in value:
            print "Failed to find key", "[" + name + "/" + DataKey + "]"
            return FALSE
    return TRUE
```

This code gives an long to long overflow exception ...

Maybe i should convert the script files to xml files and parse them with a libary (would be easier i think)

Im not able to think at the moment ... this definitely kills my brain :(

It would be great if someone could give me a hint what the error could be and how to repair it.

Edit:
The part of the code that should do the whole stuff

```
###################################################################################################
## Python Script Loader
###################################################################################################

class ScriptWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self, layer = "UI"):
        Window.__init__(self, layer)
        self.Children = []
        self.ElementDictionary = {}
    def __del__(self):
        Window.__del__(self)

    def ClearDictionary(self):
        self.Children = []
        self.ElementDictionary.clear()

    def InsertChild(self, name, child):
        self.ElementDictionary[name] = child

    def IsChild(self, name):
        return name in self.ElementDictionary

    def GetChild(self, name):
        return self.ElementDictionary[name]

    def GetChild2(self, name):
        return self.ElementDictionary.get(name, None)

class PythonScriptLoader(object):

    BODY_KEY_LIST = ( "x", "y", "width", "height" )

    #####

    DEFAULT_KEY_LIST = ( "type", "x", "y", )
    WINDOW_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", )
    IMAGE_KEY_LIST = ( "image", )
    EXPANDED_IMAGE_KEY_LIST = ( "image", )
    ANI_IMAGE_KEY_LIST = ( "images", )
    SLOT_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", "slot", )
    CANDIDATE_LIST_KEY_LIST = ( "item_step", "item_xsize", "item_ysize", )
    GRID_TABLE_KEY_LIST = ( "start_index", "x_count", "y_count", "x_step", "y_step", )
    EDIT_LINE_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", "input_limit", )
    COMBO_BOX_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", "item", )
    TITLE_BAR_KEY_LIST = ( "width", )
    HORIZONTAL_BAR_KEY_LIST = ( "width", )
    BOARD_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", )
    BOARD_WITH_TITLEBAR_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", "title", )
    BOX_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", )
    BAR_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", )
    LINE_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", )
    SLOTBAR_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", )
    GAUGE_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "color", )
    SCROLLBAR_KEY_LIST = ( "size", )
    LIST_BOX_KEY_LIST = ( "width", "height", )

    def __init__(self):
        self.Clear()

    def Clear(self):
        self.ScriptDictionary = { "SCREEN_WIDTH" : wndMgr.GetScreenWidth(), "SCREEN_HEIGHT" : wndMgr.GetScreenHeight() }
        self.InsertFunction = 0

    def LoadScriptFile(self, window, FileName):

        self.Clear()

        print "===== Load Script File : %s\n" % (FileName)

        try:
            execfile(FileName, self.ScriptDictionary)
        except:
            import dbg
            import exception
            dbg.TraceError("Failed to load script file : %s" % (FileName))
            exception.Abort("LoadScriptFile")

        Body = self.ScriptDictionary["window"]
        self.CheckKeyList("window", Body, self.BODY_KEY_LIST)

        window.ClearDictionary()
        self.InsertFunction = window.InsertChild

        window.SetPosition(int(Body["x"]), int(Body["y"]))
        window.SetSize(int(Body["width"]), int(Body["height"]))
        if "style" in  Body:
            for StyleList in Body["style"]:
                window.AddFlag(StyleList)

        self.LoadChildren(window, Body)

    def LoadChildren(self, parent, dicChildren):

        if "children" not in dicChildren:
            return FALSE

        Index = 0

        ChildrenList = dicChildren["children"]
        parent.Children = range(len(ChildrenList))
        for ElementValue in ChildrenList:
            try:
                Name = ElementValue["name"]             
            except KeyError:
                Name = ElementValue["name"] = "NONAME"

            try:
                Type = ElementValue["type"]
            except KeyError:                                
                Type = ElementValue["type"] = "window"              

            if FALSE == self.CheckKeyList(Name, ElementValue, self.DEFAULT_KEY_LIST):
                del parent.Children[Index]
                continue

            if Type == "window":
                parent.Children[Index] = ScriptWindow()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementWindow(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "button":
                parent.Children[Index] = Button()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementButton(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "radio_button":
                parent.Children[Index] = RadioButton()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementButton(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "toggle_button":
                parent.Children[Index] = ToggleButton()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementButton(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "mark":
                parent.Children[Index] = MarkBox()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementMark(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "image":
                parent.Children[Index] = ImageBox()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementImage(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "expanded_image":
                parent.Children[Index] = ExpandedImageBox()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementExpandedImage(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "ani_image":
                parent.Children[Index] = AniImageBox()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementAniImage(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "slot":
                parent.Children[Index] = SlotWindow()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementSlot(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "candidate_list":
                parent.Children[Index] = CandidateListBox()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementCandidateList(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "grid_table":
                parent.Children[Index] = GridSlotWindow()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementGridTable(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "text":
                parent.Children[Index] = TextLine()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementText(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "editline":
                parent.Children[Index] = EditLine()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementEditLine(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "titlebar":
                parent.Children[Index] = TitleBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementTitleBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "horizontalbar":
                parent.Children[Index] = HorizontalBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementHorizontalBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "board":
                parent.Children[Index] = Board()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementBoard(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "board_with_titlebar":
                parent.Children[Index] = BoardWithTitleBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementBoardWithTitleBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "thinboard":
                parent.Children[Index] = ThinBoard()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementThinBoard(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "box":
                parent.Children[Index] = Box()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementBox(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "bar":
                parent.Children[Index] = Bar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "line":
                parent.Children[Index] = Line()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementLine(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "slotbar":
                parent.Children[Index] = SlotBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementSlotBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "gauge":
                parent.Children[Index] = Gauge()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementGauge(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "scrollbar":
                parent.Children[Index] = ScrollBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementScrollBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "thin_scrollbar":
                parent.Children[Index] = ThinScrollBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementScrollBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "small_thin_scrollbar":
                parent.Children[Index] = SmallThinScrollBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementScrollBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "sliderbar":
                parent.Children[Index] = SliderBar()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementSliderBar(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "listbox":
                parent.Children[Index] = ListBox()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementListBox(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            elif Type == "listbox2":
                parent.Children[Index] = ListBox2()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementListBox2(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)
            elif Type == "listboxex":
                parent.Children[Index] = ListBoxEx()
                parent.Children[Index].SetParent(parent)
                self.LoadElementListBoxEx(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)

            else:
                Index += 1
                continue

            parent.Children[Index].SetWindowName(Name)
            if 0 != self.InsertFunction:
                self.InsertFunction(Name, parent.Children[Index])

            if "style" in  ElementValue:
                for StyleList in ElementValue["style"]:
                    parent.Children[Index].AddFlag(StyleList)

            self.LoadChildren(parent.Children[Index], ElementValue)
            Index += 1

    def CheckKeyList(self, name, value, key_list):

        for DataKey in key_list:
            if DataKey not in value:
                print "Failed to find data key", "[" + name + "/" + DataKey + "]"
                return FALSE

        return TRUE
```

Example file to load:

```
imports screenConfig
window = {
    "name" : "questiondlg",

    "x" : SCREEN_WIDTH/2 - 125,
    "y" : SCREEN_HEIGHT/2 - 52,

    "width" : 280,
    "height" : 75,

    "children" :
    (
        {
            "name" : "board",
            "type
            ...

            "children" :
            (
                {
                    "name" : "message",
                    "type" : "text",

                    "x" : 0,
                    "y" ...
                },
                {
                    "name" : "countdown_message",
                    ...
                },
            ),

        },
    ),
}
```

It's shortened a bit but it should be clear

Edit2:

login.py(line:510)

```
def __LoadScript(self, fileName):
    try:
        scriptLoader = ui.PythonScriptLoader()
        scriptLoader.LoadScriptFile(self, fileName)
    except:
        import exception
        exception.Abort("LoginWindow.__LoadScript")
```

Error Trace as requesed:

```
login.py(line:510) __LoadScript
ui.py(line:2648) LoadScriptFile
ui.py(line:2835) LoadChildren
ui.py(line:2659) LoadChildren

LoginWindow.__LoadScript - <type 'exceptions.OverflowError'>:Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Thank you

Comment: How is `key_list` produced? How about `value`? Are you sure `self.elems` is a dict? Or `parent.childs` for that matter? ("children" is the English plural btw.)

Comment: I have added the whole part of the code and an example file, things should be clearer with it. and my english is terrible some times ...

Comment: Could you also post a full stack trace of an error?

Comment: I've added the error trace, i could modify my exception class for a more detailed traceback

Comment: A standard Python traceback including the referenced source lines would be helpful. From what you posted it isn't clear if the error is thrown from the `parent.Children = range(len(ChildrenList))` line or the following `for ElementValue in ChildrenList:`. Are you positive that this is the code you are actually running: if the `range` was too large you would get `OverflowError: range() result has too many items`, but the error message you say you get `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long` comes from too large an argument to `xrange`.

Comment: I think i've found the error, in some of the i have entries like this `"color" : 0xff111111,` It's trying to convert **0xff111111** into a long int before python 2.4 it would simply return a unsigned int. On some of the element it does not overflow and the return is `'color': 4279308561L` so i think i have found it. Tracebacks with additional frame informations are the best! Im starting to love stackoverflow.

Comment: definitely found the error in my logic. i have a argb hexcode. Python tries to Convert it to a long but fails because it's  too big.